# How to reach a value in GridView recodres using VB.net code?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gridview

I have a `GridView` in `VB.net`. I have filled the grid view using the Wizard not using code.
Can I access a value in each recode in the `GridView` pragmatically using VB.net and change it ?

Comment: You mean a datagridview? It is possible to do what your asking!

Comment: Please tag the used technology, ASP.NET or Winforms.

Answer (score 0):

`DataGridViewName.Item(ColumnIndex, RowIndex).Value`

Will get the value of a cell.

Or,

`DataGridViewName.Rows(RowIndex).Item(ColumnIndex)`

You could also determine indices using,

`DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index`

and

`DataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex` or `DataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex`

Any of these should get you started.